# Git persistent branch with all but one commit

Tags: git

Normally, if I had done some work on a feature but will not be able to deploy it to master until some indefinite future time, I'd just put it in a branch and occasionally rebase that branch to the latest changes to master.

Today, I have a situation that does not quite match that common case:
I made a change to master a while back, now deep in the history. I've now decided that this change is not appropriate, so I will undo it at in master. However, I do want to save this code in a branch, because it may be relevant someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote this question, the answer became obvious.  (Stack Overflow as the ultimate rubber duck debugger?)

I just need to:

- Undo the feature in a new commit in master
- Create the new branch
- In the new branch, `git revert` the commit that undid the feature
- In the future, rebase the branch on to master as needed